# Same release repository for both hydro and indigo?

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, bloom-release, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to release a package in **Indigo** and **Hydro**. The *bloom-release* in Indigo worked fine. So, now, I've created a branch for hydro that contains some changes. When I run *bloom-release* for Hydro, can I use the same *Release repository url*?

More generally, are there any other things I have to take care of when releasing a package for both Hydro and Indigo with *bloom*?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207101/same-release-repository-for-both-hydro-and-indigo?/) by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 529 on 2015-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the same release repository for multiple ROS distributions, all the tags and branches which are created are prefixed by the ROS distribution.

There's nothing special to do for a new ROS distribution, just make sure to use different track names, so if you did:

```
$ bloom-release -r indigo -t indigo my_repo
```

Then you'll want to do this for hydro:

```
$ bloom-release -r hydro -t hydro my_repo
```

The only other thing I'd tell you to do is to make sure you version numbers are setup correctly across distributions. It's ok to have the same version number between hydro and indigo as long as they do not diverge. When you fork your source code to do something different in indigo you should also bump your minor number in your version, so that you have room to make new, non-colliding versions in hydro. For example, let's say you have 1.1.2 in both hydro and indigo, but you need to fork and release a new version only for indigo, then you should release it as 1.2.0. This is because if you need to make a new release of hydro in the future you want to continue with the patch, as 1.1.3. This way all hydro releases are 1.1.x and all indigo releases are 1.2+.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1